# Tiled xyplots, how to colour independently to mimic levelplot map?

Tags: r, lattice

I am trying to plot several lines using the lattice package to produce a tiled figure. Here is an example (which is wrong, see bellow):

[image: img1]
<sub>(source: [ubuntuone.com](http://ubuntuone.com/5ICds7K0Xjb4NCgUep3NFB))</sub>

I would like to mimic this one (in terms of the colour pattern) :

[image: img2]
<sub>(source: [ubuntuone.com](http://ubuntuone.com/33xwm3JDAx4DKc9VYzFZm9))</sub>

Both plots are colouring the same variable "subset$speed1DaboveT". The first is done with xyplot the second with levelplot.

My problem is that the one with the curves is not colouring correctly, possibly because i am asking the wrong thing. I have followed this example from another question (which, importantly, is a single figure):

```
dfrm <- data.frame( y=c(rnorm(10),rnorm(10)),
                x=1:10, 
                grp=rep(c("a","b"),each=10))

xyplot(y~x, group=grp, type="l", data=dfrm, col=c("red","blue"))
```

By doing:

```
keys=unique(subset$speed1DaboveT)
theseCol= colF(length(keys))

pp= xyplot( freq~patch|B+G
        ,data=subset
        ,scales=list( x=list(cex=0.5), y=list(cex=0.5,lim=c(0,1.1)) )
        ,strip = FALSE
        ,t='l'
        ,group=speed1DaboveT
        ,col=theseCol
        ,lwd=2
        ,cex=0.5
        ,panel = function(x, y, col, ...) {                
                   panel.xyplot(x, y, col=col, ...) 
               }
        )
```

In my case i am using 2 factors (B and G) and the example has none. This may mean that the colours given to xyplot should perhaps follow a different order? Anyone knows how to?

Answer (score 0):

So, i failed to notice that the range would not be the same. Sorry for the question, things were solved once i forced the colour range of the xyplot to be the same as the levelplot, that is [0,0.16]

thanks

Comment: You can delete questions.